# Is there an equivalent to @Before or beforeEach in Scalatest

Tags: scalatest

Test frameworks like `jasmine` and `junit` provide ways to configure the test environment before each test is run. Is something similar available in `scalatest` and `playspec`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In scalatest you can use traits `BeforeAndAfterAll` and `BeforeAndAfterEach` to add such methods, then you need to override them fe:

```
class BaseTest extends FlatSpec with BeforeAndAfterAll with BeforeAndAfterEach{

  override def beforeAll(): Unit = {
    super.beforeAll()
    //your logic here
  }

  //..

}
```